# I'm missing some zone files, and I need them to configure some SPF settings. How do I create them?

Tags: centos, spf, bind, zones

I recently noticed that my recently setup domain, example.com, was being used to send spam.  So, I decided to fix this and found some information on SPF configuration, and that I'd need to go edit the appropriate .zone file in my server.  Well, that was fine and dandy and seemed pretty simple--*except I don't seem to have the ones I need!*

Well, lo and behold, all I found (running Centos 5.5 under /var/named) were the following *.zone files:  localdomain.zone and localhost.zone, none of which contained any information relative to my server's IP address or domain name.

So I checked the files named.conf and named.rfc1912.zone, but neither one made reference to my domain name, example.com, or my IP address.  They only make reference to localhost, it appears.

Where did I go wrong in all this?  I haven't found any information on creating zones to put SPF information in them, just putting SPF data in pre-existing zone files.

Thanks a bunch,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your hosting the DNS for your domain ?

It doesnt sound like you are, `whios example.com` have a look in the results for `Name Server:` and see if those point to your server, if not all the work in the world with bind wont help ;)

Comment: Well, look at that.  I guess my inexperience is showing here--we're set up with GoDaddy, and I can configure it all through them with their nice little GUI.  Thanks, you've saved me a lot of head scratching.

Answer (score 0):

Zone files are normally found in /etc/named or /etc/bind. But are not named with .zone suffix.